# Transferring and saving MultipartFile instance

Tags: java, java-io, multipartfile

I have the following method, with the simple aim to store the contents  of a given `MultipartFile` instance under a specified directory:

```java
private void saveOnDisk(final String clientProductId, final MultipartFile image, final String parentDirectoryPath, final String fileSeparator) throws IOException
    {
        final File imageFile = new File(parentDirectoryPath + fileSeparator + clientProductId + image.getOriginalFilename());
        image.transferTo(imageFile);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        out. //... ? How do we proceed? OutputStream::write() requires a byte array or int as parameter
    }
```

For what it might be worth, the `MultipartFile` instance is going to contain an image file which I receive on a REST API I'm building.

I've checked some SO posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232902/java-saving-opening-file-objects) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847994/spring-mvc-save-uploaded-multipartfile-to-specific-folder) but this problem is not quite touched: I'm effectively looking to create an entirely new image file and store it on a specified location on disk: the method `write()` of `OutputStream`, given that it requires `byte[]` or `int` params, doesn't seem to be fitting my use case. Any ideas?

Comment: From which library is `MultipartFile` from? Is it `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile`? Calling `transferTo(...)` might already be enough to store the file. The constructor `FileOutputStream(File)` is not very clear regarding this, but it actually truncates the existing file, which is likely why you are thinking that it did not work. Therefore just omit the creation of the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Yes, it is that class' instance. So just creating the `File` instance and doing a `transferTo()` towards it from my `MultipartFile` instance also flushes the elements to disk? I will try this in a toy project.

Comment: And you really **should not include `image.getOriginalFilename()` in the file name**. The multipart file name is client controlled and despite browsers normally not sending directory names an attacker can easily provide an arbitrary name ([cURL examples](https://superuser.com/a/149335)). See also [OWASP File Upload Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/File_Upload_Cheat_Sheet.html#filename-sanitization) and [Unrestricted File Upload Vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload).

Comment: And there was no way I could know that without this information. Very appreciated.

Comment: Did using only `transferTo(...)` work? If so I will write up these comments as answer then.

Comment: Unfortunately, so far it has *not* worked. I am not seeing a file dumped on disk.